# How can I check if a particular jQuery UI function is available and use a different function if it isn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, graceful-degradation

I'm writing a jQuery plugin and I would like my code to take advantage of the jQuery UI `show(effect, [options], [speed], [callback])` and `hide(effect, [options], [speed], [callback])` functions, which allow you to show and hide elements with a nice animation.

However, I'd also like my plugin to degrade gracefully if jQuery UI isn't available, switching back to use the basic, non-animating `show()` and `hide()` functions present in the standard jQuery API.

I'll need to test for the show and hide functions specifically, as even if jQuery UI *is* available it could potentially be a custom version, without the Effects components included.

At first I thought that I might be able to do something like:

```
if(typeof myelement.show('blind', 'slow') == 'undefined')
{
    myelement.show('blind', 'slow');
}
else
{
    myelement.show();
}
```

But of course this doesn't work, as even if UI isn't present, `show()` is still a function, it just has a different signature—so `typeof` returns `object` in either case.

So, what's the best way for me to check if jQuery UI is available to my plugin? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for an effect like this:

```
function hasEffect(effect) {
    return $.effects && $.effects[effect];
}
```

Then you can use that anywhere:

```
if(hasEffect('blind')) {
  myelement.show('blind', 'slow');
} else {
  myElement.show();
}
//or, you can shorten it further:
//$.fn.show.apply(myelement, hasEffect('blind') ? ['blind','slow'] : []);​
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5DxWv/), check/uncheck jQuery UI on the left and click "Run" up top to see it in action.  This works because effects are declared like this:

```
$.effects.blind = function(o) { ...effecty stuff... };
```

For example, you can see ["blind" here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.effects.blind.js).  The reason I  check for both `$.effects` and `$.effects.effect` in the code above is you can only download [*some* of the effects when you download jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download), so this accounts for that possibility.

Comment: Great, thanks—exactly what I was looking for. I'm surprised that function isn't part of jQuery; this must be quite a common requirement for plugin authors.

Answer (score 1):

Nick's function worked perfectly; for consistency, I ended up adding it as a jQuery utility function from within my plugin code:

```
$.extend({
    hasEffect: function (effect) {
        return $.effects && $.effects[effect];
    }
});
```

So now I can call `$.hasEffect(effectname)` anywhere I want to check for the presence of a particular jQuery UI effect.